# Difference between height/width and LayoutParams.height/width in TableRow android

Tags: android

In my code in Kotlin I have a row which is an instance of TableRow, I would like to set it's height and width as MATCH_PARENT.
Anyway, I found that there are two type of height and width; one which is an instance of row.layoutParams, and one which is an instance of row itself.
So my question is, what is the difference between these two? and how can I set the height and width to match parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it like this -:

```
  TableRow tablerow = new TableRow(this); 
  tablerow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

and TableRow does not have MATCH_PARENT directly, You need to use layout Params

```
TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Do you know also what is the difference between these two:
    tablerow.height    &    tablerow.layoutParams.height?

Comment: @Samp Bro there is no direct method height of table row, it's a View Class method, because TableRow extends LinearLayout, LinearLayout extends ViewGroup and ViewGroup extends View  thats why we have that height method (which means getHeight() in View Java Class). In Kotlin we can use it as height variable